# Se puede actualizar el origen de un Biding WPF

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf

a ver si pudieran ayudarme.
Tengo dos TextBox cada uno en una clase diferente, y necesito que lo que se escriba en uno se muestre en el otro.

El que debe recibir los datos lo tengo así en xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="mTxtPuntosLocal" Text="{Binding AddPuntoLocal, ElementName=ventana}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="100"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  Width="135"/>
```

Ahora mismo cojo los datos para probar que recibe así:

```
string varPuntoLocal;       
        public string AddPuntoLocal
        {
            get
            {
                return  "3";
            }
            set
            {
                varPuntoLocal = value;
            }
        }
```

Ahora mismo recibo el "3" siempre. Necesito que me muestre lo que hay dentro de otro textbox de otra clase, como deberia referenciarlo dentro del Biding.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he encontrado en StackOverflow en inglés la respuesta a tu pregunta. Espero te sirva [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836431/data-binding-between-two-texboxes-in-different-windows) dejo el link y te copio la información.

> Lo que tienes que hacer es pasar una referencia a la primera ventana o
>   el objeto que va a actualizar la propiedad de texto a la segunda
>   ventana, que es propiedad DataContext hará para que, a continuación,
>   puede obligar a los segundos controles de las ventanas a la misma.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string TestString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestStringProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestStringProperty =  DependencyProperty.Register("TestString", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // setup the test string.
        TestString = "this is a test.";

        // Create the second window and pass this window as it's data context.
        Window1 newWindow = new Window1()
        {
            DataContext = this
        };
        newWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml** - Tomar nota de la línea DataContext en la declaración de la ventana.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        >
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TestString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="91,84,185,189" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```